# Laravel, how to categorize (group) Eloquent result?

Tags: laravel

So I have a table that looks like this:

```
Name    Class    Remarks    
Test1   C1       passed
Test2   C1       failed
Test3   C1       passed
Test4   C2       passed
```

And what I'm trying to output is :

```
Class   Name   Remarks
C1      Test1  passed
        Test2  failed
        Test3  passed
C2      Test4  passed
```

I am trying to load it by grouping first the class then loop through the collection. I'm not sure if that was the best solution. I'm thinking there might be a much reliable approach to this kind of requirement.

Comment: How many rows are you likely to have in this database? Is it going to remain quite small (e.g. a few hundred rows at most) or will it potentially grow to be in the 1000's?

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent result is a collection, you can just use collection [groupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-groupby):

```php
$result->groupBy('Class');
```